# Outer Join in SQL Server 2012 with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

I would like to have a result set having join with left or right outer join on multiple columns instead of one column condition .

I have tried like this. But it only returns result set having outer join based on first column or more appropriately primary key and foreign key columns only.

```
...
    a 
left outer join 
    b on (a.id = b.id and a.code = b.code)
```

Comment: Please remove the irrelevant tags from your question.

Comment: Please, provide a samples of data before and after join. How do you check if second column join is not working?

Comment: That is the correct way to do it, although you don't need the brackets. There must be something else wrong in your code.

Comment: Show us the complete statement